# How to setup Appinsights with azure search javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-search, appinsights

From the Azure Search documentation I know that we have to get some search information to setup appinsights telemetry.

The problem is: How do I get SearchID information from the @azure/search-documents SearchDocumentResult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `@azure/search-documents` module, you can set up your client and add custom headers to operations like so:

```js
const { SearchClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require("@azure/search-documents");

const indexName = "nycjobs";
const apiKey = "252044BE3886FE4A8E3BAA4F595114BB";

const client = new SearchClient(
  `https://azs-playground.search.windows.net/`,
  indexName,
  new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey)
);

async function main() {
  var searchId = '';

  const searchResults = await client.search('Microsoft', {
    top: 3,
    requestOptions: {
      customHeaders: {
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'x-ms-azs-searchid',
        'x-ms-azs-return-searchid': 'true'
      },
      shouldDeserialize: (response) => {
        searchId = response.headers.get('x-ms-azs-searchid');
        return true;
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(`Search ID: ${searchId}\n`);

  for await (const result of searchResults.results) {
    console.log(`${result.document.business_title}\n${result.document.job_description}\n`);
  }
}
```

It seems that currently the only way to get them out is the `shouldDeserialize` callback as shown in the example since it gives you the raw response including the headers before deserializing when the headers are stripped from some objects, such as those paged response objects returned by `search`.

Comment: Hi, I just used your answer in a project, so thank you! However is there some place in the Azure documentation that `shouldDeserialize` is mentioned? Is this something everybody knows about?

Comment: It's declared in the type information if you're using TypeScript; otherwise, you'll have to look at code in the repo at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you care more about search query telemetry and not indexer telemetry, but please correct me if I'm wrong.  Is this documentation page helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-traffic-analytics

From that page, here is how you set the searchId:

```
request.setRequestHeader("x-ms-azs-return-searchid", "true");
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-ms-azs-searchid");
var searchId = request.getResponseHeader('x-ms-azs-searchid');
```

Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: You are right that I care more about search query, but this is using REST APIs, and I'm using the @azure/search-documents SDK, so I don't have access to the request itself, but to a SearchDocumentResult object.

Comment: Got it!  I've asked Heath on the SDK team to comment; see his response.  Does that help?